# Spring MVC, redirect to error after Rest call exception

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm performing a Rest request in one of my controllers and I'd like to redirect to my error view if the request went wrong (404, 503 ...)
My controller calls this function :

```
public String functionTest(){

        String date, res;
        String url = "myRestUrl/{param}";
        Map<String, String> uriParams = new HashMap<>();
        uriParams.put("param", "param");
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(createHeaders());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestErrorHandler());
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.buildAndExpand(uriParams).toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        res= response.getBody().getMyResult();

        return res;

    }
```

And here is my Rest error handler :

```
public class RestErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

        //Here I need to use a ModelAndView to redirect to error view but I'm not anymore in my controller

    }

}
```

I guess I'm doing it wrong, do you have any solutions ?

Comment: You have only half of the answer. One way to achieve what you want would be to throw an exception in your `handleError()` method and then handle it in your controller.

Comment: If I throw a IOException in handleError method I can't catch anything in my functionTest

Comment: RestTemplate throws a `RestClientException` if it encounters an error. This exception is a runtime exception and therefore does not extend IOException. See edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather simplistic way to achieve what you need. If you would like more control/flexibility, refer to this Spring [blog article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

In your (client) `RestErrorHandler`:

```
public class RestErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) 
        throws IOException {

        // Do some stuff here ...

        // This could be your own exception, for example.
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller (or refer to the article above if you want other options):

```
// Your requestMappings here ...
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    // Do stuff and redirect to your error view.
    return mav;
}
```

**EDIT:** Another solution would be to catch Spring's `RestClientException`, which is a `RuntimeException` thrown by RestTemplate when it encounters an error:

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(...);
} catch (RestClientException ex) {
    // Do stuff here ...
}
```

Comment: The second solution with RestclientException works well, thank you but I can't get the status code from the exception

Comment: I saw that HttpClientErrorException is better for that but the exception is not thrown